# Group by a subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

What is the best way of making the following **`T-SQL`** query valid:

```
select
    count(*),
    (... a subquery that returns one result ...) as [Bar]
from Foo foo
group by [Bar]
```

Comment: Please explain what the query is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Its supposed to be grouping by the result of a subquery. I've simplified it so you don't have to read so much.

Comment: @cbp - trust me, Martin knows *that* much. Perhaps you could post some sample data and expected output. It would clear things up. For starters, I don't see any reason why you include the `Office`table. It looks redundant to me.

Comment: @cbp - The main reason for the question was because the subquery had `top 1` with no `order by`. The result of this is not guaranteed so I wanted to know what the intent was. You can always `group by` by chucking the whole thing into a CTE then doing a `SELECT ... GROUP BY` from that but if we understand what the correlated sub query is meant to be doing there might be a better way.

Comment: OK thanks, actually I was asking the question out of curiosity so the exact query is not important. You are right, the whole thing can be wrapped in a CTE. It seems strange that grouping by a subquery projection is not valid (especially because it is easy to replicate using a CTE).

Comment: Ah right it gives the error "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause." Not sure of the reason for that limitation. Whether it just isn't implemented or whether it is because implementing this would violate some principle or other.

Comment: @cbp: There's a similar issue with ranking functions. You can't use them just anywhere, e.g. not in the WHERE clause, which seems just as strange. However, just like with your subquery, you can easily employ a CTE to work around that. So, when they throw at me something like '*This* or *that is not allowed here* or *there*', there doesn't seem to me to be much what could be done about that (other than working around that).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       (SELECT TOP 1 name 
        FROM   sys.objects 
        ORDER  BY object_id%number) name 
FROM   master..spt_values 
WHERE  number > 0 
GROUP BY (SELECT TOP 1 name 
            FROM   sys.objects 
            ORDER  BY object_id%number)
```

Gives the error

> Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery
>   in an expression  used for the group
>   by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Maybe someone else can answer why this is not allowed. A couple of ways which are valid

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       oa.name 
FROM   master..spt_values 
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 name 
                    from   sys.objects 
                    ORDER  BY object_id%number) oa 
WHERE  number > 0 
GROUP  BY oa.name
```

and

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT number, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 name 
        from   sys.objects 
        ORDER  BY object_id%number) name 
FROM   master..spt_values 
WHERE  number > 0  
)
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       name 
FROM T 
GROUP BY name
```